# Real Analysis - limits and differentiation

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a real-valued function $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties

1. $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{h(x)}{x^{2}}=K$
2. h is differentiable everywhere

a. Find $h(0), h^{'}(0)$

b. Find a function $g$ such that properties 1 and 2 hold and $h^{''}(0)$ does not exist.

-> I've attempted to solve this using the limit definition of the derivative for $h{'}(0)$ but I keep going around in circles. Can someone please help.

Comment: Do you mean $g(x)$ instead of $x^2$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and $f(x)$ does *not* converge to zero, then the quantity

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

is not bounded in a neighborhood of zero.

Comment: Can you explain further.

Comment: @user116515 $K$ is a number, right? And $x^2 \to 0$, so the numerator of the quotient you're considering must .......

Comment: Hi @T.Bongers , I stumbled across this question and am also trying to solve this. With your hint, I have that $h(0)=0$ and $h'(0)=0$, but also that $h''(0)=K$, which is probably wrong, considering part (b) of OP's question. Could you give a hint for that part so that I might figure out what I've done wrong?

Comment: ..be the product of two functions? one being $x^{2}$ since f(x) does not converge to zero and the denominator converges to 0 as x approaches 0? If so, I'm thinking that the other function in the product would be one which converges to K but I am unsure where to go from there

Comment: @blf The first two are correct, but we really can't say anything about $h''(0)$: You'd need to take a difference quotient $$\frac{f'(x)}{x}$$ to study the second derivative, but we know nothing about the derivative away from zero.

Comment: @user116515 You have a fraction, and the denominator goes to zero. So by my hint, the numerator has to go to zero as well.

Comment: @T.Bongers Ah thanks, I see what you mean.

Comment: @T.Bongers However, I am still having trouble constructing an example for (b)...

Answer (score 1):

By T. Bongers's hint above, if $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}h(x) \ne 0$, then it is impossible for $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{h(x)}{x^2}$ to be finite. So, $h(0) = 0$.

Note that $$K = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{h(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{h(x)}{x}}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x-0}}{x}.$$

By the same reasoning as before, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{h(x)-h(0)}{x-0}$ must be $0$ if the last limit above is finite. So $h'(0)=0$.

---

How can we make $h''(0)$ not exist? Look at [this](http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_differentiable_function_need_not_be_continuous) for inspiration.

Let $$h(x) = \begin{cases} Kx^2 + x^3 \sin \frac 1 x & x \ne 0 \\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}.$$ Then $$\dfrac{h(x)}{x^2} = K+x\sin\frac 1 x \to K$$ as $x \to 0$.

Moreover, $$h'(x) =\begin{cases} 2Kx + x^2 \sin \frac 1 x - x \cos \frac 1 x & x \ne 0 \\ 0 & x = 0\end{cases}.$$

But
$$\frac{h'(x)-h'(0)}{x-0} = \frac{h'(x)}{x} = 2K + x \sin \frac 1 x - \cos \frac 1 x$$
does not have a limit as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $K \neq 0$, it means that $h(x)=Kx^2+O(x^3)$, because otherwise the limit would be either $0$ or infinite. You can easily see that both $h(0)$ and $h'(0)$ are 0.

Comment: I think your use of $O(x^3)$ is misleading... what is wrong with $h(x) = Kx^2 + x^4$? Also, do you have any hints for part (b)?

Comment: Can you explain what $O(x^{3})$ represents. I am unsure how you came up with that expression for h(x). Furthermore, how can we conclude that K is non-zero.

Comment: For $x \to 0 \ x^4=O(x^3)$

Comment: @Alex Oh right, sorry. So technically, you mean $O(x^{2+\epsilon})$?

Comment: Yes for $\varepsilon>0$

Comment: @user116515 $O(x^3)$ represents a quantity that is $\le Cx^3$ as $x \to 0$; [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) for more information.

Comment: I looked over the link above and the most relevant section I noticed was the 'Infinitesimal Asymptotics' in which they discuss Big O describing the error term. I apologize but I haven't been exposed to that in my real analysis course. Is there an alternative approach to this problem?